# form button styling, font-size and box shadow problems

Tags: html, css, forms, button

I'm trying to style a button in a from besides a input text field.
Everyting works unless I lower the font-size of the button (which is I need to do) and give my button a background gradient.
If I lower the font-size (or set anything except 1em) there is a mystical space below my button text and I have no idea where it comes from. If I raise the padding to match the lowered font-size, the space is still there.
If I add a gradient to the button the box shadow of the surrounding form vanishes.

How can I fix both?

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/WTrQy/

HTML:

```
<section class="grid-100 search">
    <header class="none">
            <h1>Schnell finden</h1>

    </header>
    <form class="grid-90 grid-parent" action="action.php">
        <input type="text" aria-required="true" placeholder="Suche nach PLZ oder Ort" class="grid-80 mobile-grid-80">
        <button class="grid-20 mobile-grid-20">Suchen</button>
    </form>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
section.search h1 {
    margin-top: 1.7em;
    margin-bottom: .5em;
    font-size: 1.285714285714286em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

section.search form {
    margin-top: 1em;
    background-color: #353535;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0.3em;
    -moz-border-radius: 0.3em;
    border-radius: 0.3em;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0.2em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0.2em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0.2em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

section.search form input, section.search form button {
    padding: 0.7em;
}

section.search form input {
    -webkit-border-radius: 0.2em 0 0 0.2em;
    -moz-border-radius: 0.2em 0 0 0.2em;
    border-radius: 0.2em 0 0 0.2em;
}

section.search form button {
    font-size: 0.7em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0.2em 0.2em 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0.2em 0.2em 0;
    border-radius: 0 0.2em 0.2em 0;

    background: #d60e64;
    background:
        url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #d60e64 0%, #6c0437 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #d60e64),
        color-stop(100%, #6c0437));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #d60e64 0%, #6c0437 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #d60e64 0%, #6c0437 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #d60e64 0%, #6c0437 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #d60e64 0%, #6c0437 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(   startColorstr='#d60e64',
        endColorstr='#6c0437', GradientType=0);
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
    /*font-size: 0.7857142857142857em;*/
}

section.search button:hover {
    background: #a4145a;
    background:
        url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #a4145a 0%, #58022c 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #a4145a),
        color-stop(100%, #58022c));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #a4145a 0%, #58022c 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #a4145a 0%, #58022c 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #a4145a 0%, #58022c 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #a4145a 0%, #58022c 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(   startColorstr='#a4145a',
        endColorstr='#58022c', GradientType=0);
}

section.search form input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    font-size: 0.8em;
}

section.search form input:-moz-placeholder {
    /* Firefox 18 - */
    font-size: 0.8em;
}

section.search form input::-moz-placeholder {
    /* Firefox 19 + */
    font-size: 0.8em;
}

section.search form input:-ms-input-placeholder {
    /* Internet Explorer 1em is by purpose */
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

Comment: Please try removing padding to the button and give fix height to the button.

Comment: Sure that would fix it, but everything should be responsive and fixed widths or heights is not something I'd like to do. I mean this space must come from somewhere, not? Probably knowing where it comes from could fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button is now not as tall as your textbox as you are adding padding in ems so with the smaller font size you will have less padding on the button than the textbox.

add the following line below your other padding line this will fix the issue:

```
section.search form button {
    padding: 1.2em 0.7em 1.1em 0.7em;
}
```

Your box shadow is not displaying as 0.2em is too small a width for the shadow, if you increase this to at least 0.5em you should be able to see your shadow

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/WTrQy/1/)